# Logstash conf Error : failed to parse date field of type [date] in document:failed to parse date :with format[strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am working on a ELK stack assignment

I am getting logstash configuration error in date format, while configuring for multiple components grok pattern. I have a date as 21-Feb-2023 07:30:55.000 (In component3 if block) and I am using dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS in the date filter. As I have multiple components, So I am using if statements. (And filebeat.yml is taking care of these settings.)

As I am using different date formats, I tried using them comma separated. But its not working !

```
input {
          beats {
            port => 5044
          }        
}
 
filter {
    grok {
                match => { "[log][file][path]" => "%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:filename}\.log" }
        }
        
    if [fields][component] == "component1" {
                grok {
                        
                        match => { "message" => "(?<context>.*)?t=%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logTime} level=%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} msg=%{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}" }                       
                }
        }
    if [fields][component] == "component2" {
                grok {
                        
                        match => { "message" => "%{MONTH} %{NUMBER} %{TIME} %{HOSTNAME:host} influxd-systemd-start.sh\[%{NUMBER}\]: ts=%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logTime} lvl=%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}" }                        
                }
        }
        
    if [fields][component] == "component3" {
            grok {
                pattern_definitions => {
 
                "CUSTOMMONTH" => "(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)"
                "CUSTOMTIMESTAMP" => "%{MONTHDAY}-%{CUSTOMMONTH}-%{YEAR} %{TIME}"
                }
                match => { "message" => "%{CUSTOMTIMESTAMP:logTime} %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} \[%{DATA:thread}\] %{JAVACLASS:class} %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}" }
            }   
    }   
        
 
date{       
      match => ["logTime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss","dd-MMM-yyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSS", "ISO8601"]
      timezone => "XXX/AAA"
      target => "@timestamp"
    }
}
 
output {
  elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "logs-analytics_%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Error I am getting :

```
"failed to parse field [logTime] of type [date] in document with id 'hjfghfjhfkjhg'. Preview of field's value: '21-Feb-2023 07:30:55.000'", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse date field [21-Feb-2023 07:30:55.000] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"date_time_parse_exception", "reason"=>"Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"
```

Could any one please suggest how to deal with multiple date formats in grok pattern date filter..

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

you provided the pattern `dd-MMM-yyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSS` but it should be `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS` to parse the field value reported in the error log (`21-Feb-2023 07:30:55.000`)

Comment: Hi @glenacota,                                                                                                                                                 I am trying as below :    But same error :                                                                         
 date{
      match => ["logTime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss","dd-MMM-yyy HH:mm:ss.SSS", "ISO8601"]
      timezone => "Europe/Dublin"
      target => "@timestamp"
    }

Comment: also for the same entry? could you please provide the error log, so that we can have a look at the value? I tested the fixed configuration with the value that caused your error in the log you already posted, and it worked